# Finding documents having specific values in subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, find, mongodb-query

In MongoDB, suppose we have a collection `items` with the following sample data:

```js
[
   {name: "A", locations: [{country: "USA"}, {country: "Germany"}]},
   {name: "B", locations: [{country: "USA"}],
   {name: "C", locations: [{country: "France"}, {country: "Germany"}]},
   {name: "D", locations: [{country: "Germany"}]},
   {name: "E", locations: [{country: "USA"}, {country: "UK"}]}
]
```

1. How can we get the `name` field of all the documents having only `country: "Germany"` in `locations` subdocument?

   **Example:** Using the sample collection `items` above, then executing the above query should return `[{name: "D"}]`
2. How can we get the `name` field of all the documents with `locations` subdocument not having `country: France` or `country: "Germany"` (or both) as an element?

   **Example:** Using the sample collection `items` above, then executing the above query should return `[{name: "B"}, {name: "E"}]`

I've read the documentation, and tried many things, and I ended up handling it using two steps. Querying with the most specific query I came up with, then filtering unneeded documents through looping over the documents (array) programmatically. I would prefer to know if either of the previous queries could be achieved directly by a single query.

**Note:** The documents/queries are only samples, and the documents/queries I am dealing with are different.

Comment: 1-db.test.find({"locations": [{ "country" : "Germany" }]})

Comment: That will only work if we assume `locations` will only contain one key/value `country: "Germany"`. If there are other key/value pairs, it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can we get the name field of all the documents having only country: "Germany" in locations subdocument?

The [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/size/) operator will come in handy for this:

```js
db.foo.find({locations:{$size:1}, "locations.country":"Germany"})
```

> How can we get the name field of all the documents with locations subdocument not having country: France or country: "Germany" (or both) as an element?

The [`$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator will come in handy for this:

```js
db.foo.find({"locations.country":{$nin:["Germany", "France"]}})
```

Comment: Great answer. Do I assume If I want to get only documents having exactly both locations "Germany" and "France", then I would do: `db.items.find({locations:{$size:2}, "locations.country": {$in:["Germany","France"]}})`?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to use the [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator to match **all** of the elements in the given array: `db.items.find({locations:{$size:2}, "locations.country": {$all:["Germany","France"]}})`